# How to Revert the Squash Commits

Tags: git, github

I have made a mistake to squash commit, so my  `git reflog` look like this :

```
    868efc8 (HEAD -> jdbc_exporter, origin/jdbc_exporter) HEAD@{0}: revert: Revert "Azure JDBC Changes"
    699546a HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
    699546a HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
    699546a HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to 699546a
    699546a HEAD@{4}: rebase (finish): returning to refs/heads/jdbc_exporter
    699546a HEAD@{5}: rebase (pick): Azure JDBC Changes
    4a63871 HEAD@{6}: rebase (squash): parent 033f1e42b85af682f55a79f4f5bef401af0a1125
    eab2f79 HEAD@{7}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 21 commits.
    002f259 HEAD@{8}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 20 commits.
    a3482a5 HEAD@{9}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 19 commits.
    4d46620 HEAD@{10}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 18 commits.
    855e0b9 HEAD@{11}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 17 commits.
    6b81fa9 HEAD@{12}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 16 commits.
    f40ca89 HEAD@{13}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 15 commits.
    0008502 HEAD@{14}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 14 commits.
    c3acb29 HEAD@{15}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 13 commits.
    3be9992 HEAD@{16}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 12 commits.
    73c2394 HEAD@{17}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 11 commits.
    fcc7b05 HEAD@{18}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 10 commits.
    770d5d4 HEAD@{19}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 9 commits.
    19bf9eb HEAD@{20}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 8 commits.
    fbba96b HEAD@{21}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 7 commits.
    ad58a66 HEAD@{22}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 6 commits.
    e9e5ad1 HEAD@{23}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 5 commits.
    74cb8e4 HEAD@{24}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 4 commits.
    0ccc2cc HEAD@{25}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 3 commits.
    fcc3a94 HEAD@{26}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 2 commits.
    cf222f7 HEAD@{27}: rebase (continue): parent 033f1e42b85af682f55a79f4f5bef401af0a1125
    02b73ef HEAD@{28}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 7 commits.
    d021157 HEAD@{29}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 6 commits.
    46787cf HEAD@{30}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 5 commits.
    54d1843 HEAD@{31}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 4 commits.
    95a4b10 HEAD@{32}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 3 commits.
    66c7cb2 HEAD@{33}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 2 commits.
95a4b10 HEAD@{32}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 3 commits.
66c7cb2 HEAD@{33}: rebase (squash): # This is a combination of 2 commits.
8abe618 HEAD@{34}: rebase (pick): DB CC
```

I want to revert all these squash want to have changes for  `699546a HEAD@{5}: rebase (pick): Azure JDBC Changes` only how i can do it ?

Not sure how to do that not able to have my changes only.

Comment: I think you want to reset before the squashes. `699546a` already contains all the squashed commits.

Comment: @knittl if i reset to `8abe618` so my changes will be lost ? `699546a` contain my changes

Comment: I don't know what your history looks like. Can you show the top output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph`? Which commits (changes) do you want to drop, which do you want to keep, which do you want to squash or reorder?

Comment: If you want to know whether reseting to `8abe618` will discard your changes, you can inspect that commit. `git diff 8abe618` will tell you whether your current head has the same code as that commit (in which case the output will be empty, I expect that will be the case), You can also run `git log --oneline 8abe618` and that should show all your non-squashed commits. If that's all as I expect, then a simple `git reset 8abe618` should be all you need.

Comment: But actually, I think you're not showing us enough of your reflog. The commit that has all your non-squashed commits is probably older in your reflog. There should be one labelled `rebase (start)`, the one before that should be where you were before you rebased. That's probably the commit you want to start working from again. You'll most likely have to redo your whole rebase operation again, I hope it was not too complex!